# Implementing a 2D interactive area in WPF using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

We are developing an application in C# and WPF, that requires the user to select one or more items in a 2D area using the mouse in order to edit their corresponding properties in text fields below it. I am new to C# and WPF and currently trying to figure out the best way to implement this.

The figure below shows a scetch of what I have in mind. Each circle represents an item of the same type whose properties/values can differ between instances. The user should be able to select a single or multiple items using either Mouse-Click, Mouse-Click+Ctrl, or Mouse-Drag (by selecting an area). Furthermore it would ideal if similarly columns and/or rows could selected by selecting one or more of their numbers/letters.

Furthermore the color of the items should change border-color to signal their selection-status (selected vs. unselected) and fill-color to signal their contained values and make groups of identical items easily identifiable.

[image]

The number of shown items (cirlces) needs to scale to at least 400. In the future perhaps 2000 or more, so performance could become an issue. By then the area would likely also have to be zoomable. However at the moment ease of implentation has highest priority.

I am currently reading up on WPF and it seems, that the unified grid along with templating to fill it might be an option. However, I am unsure if the performance will be sufficient(?).

I am hopeful, that someone has already implemented something similar and perhaps could recommend a direction for further investigation. Thanks in advance and best regards.

Comment: A ListBox control with a custom control template and item template, set to allow multiple selection, and bound to a list of suitable model objects, would get you part of the way. However the "click on row/column heading to select all in row/column" requirement is trickier: your model objects would have to know which row and column they were in for starters, and the layout panel used by your ListBox would have to be a Grid (for which you would have to "hard-code" the number of rows & columns). You would also need some code-behind to change the selections.

Comment: @StevenRands I was planning on hard-coding the number of row & columns anyway, since they will be known from the start. Thanks for suggesting ListBox. I will look into it. I have also been looking into the [MultiSelector Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.multiselector%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which inherits from ItemsControl, since I have found a number of examples that might help me using ItemsControl. Do you think that might be a viable way?

Comment: I hadn't come across **MultiSelector** before: not sure of its exact purpose, as its base class **Selector** (from which **ListBox** derives) supports multiple selection anyway. Regardless, as it's an abstract class you can't use it directly. I would stick with **ListBox** to be honest: it is very easy to template and should provide the features you need.

Comment: You might want to look at Dr WPF's series of articles [ItemsControl: A to Z](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/). I found these very useful, and they certainly opened my eyes to the power of WPF lists and binding.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion/link. I will take look at it!