# Instance binding in WPF with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am new to `WPF` and the `MVVM` pattern and a little confused on how to achieve `data-binding` to pre-existing instances. I understand that in `MVVM` you have the `Model="business logic"`, `ViewModel="presentation logic"`, `View="actual presentation"`.

Unfortunately I am currently unable to figure out how you would go about binding your View to existing instances of the `ViewModel` and corresponding Model. I have found for example this [MVVM tutorial](http://www.markwithall.com/programming/2013/03/01/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example.html), which I liked, but it also just creates the `Model inside the ViewModel`.

So how would I go about using previously instantiated Models from my underlying application?

**EDIT**: So I am getting around to trying out the method proposed by Gusdor in a small test project, but cannot get it to work. I am getting an error `'WpfBindingTesting.App.MyViewModel' is a 'field', but used like a 'type'` in App.xaml.cs (see below). I hope somebody catches what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

ViewModel:

```
namespace WpfBindingTesting
{
    class ViewModel
    {
        private List<string> names;
        public List<string> Names
        {
            get { return names; }
            set { names = value; }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Names = new List<string> { "string1", "string2", "string3" };
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace WpfBindingTesting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfBindingTesting.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext = "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
        >

        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Names}"
                Height="50"
                >
            </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
namespace WpfBindingTesting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App(){
            MainWindow View = new MainWindow();
            ViewModel MyViewModel = new ViewModel();
            View.DataContext = MyViewModel; // this give error: 'WpfBindingTesting.App.MyViewModel' is a 'field', but used like a 'type'
            //view.DataContext = new ViewModel();
            //view.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear ... Make it more `readable` by providing some `demo code`

Comment: Put your instances on the View Model and then use them.

Comment: What are you models? what kind of application do you develop? What kind of navigation (Tabs, NavigationFrame, Windows...)

Comment: I don't have code ATM. The application is an interface a simple interface, where I can select different object for editing. See this unanswered my unanswered question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284545/implementing-a-2d-interactive-area-in-wpf-using-c-sharp for details. I advancing well on the interface, but at some point, I will need to be able to load different configurations of the edited objects from disk and I can't see ATM how this will be done using the MVVM pattern.

Comment: I am working on a user control to select different objects for editing. See my unanswered question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284545/implementing-a-2d-interactive-area-in-wpf-using-c-sharp for details. Currently I am just binding to instance from within XAML, doing e.g.: `<substratePresenter:TargetCollection x:Key="Targets"/>`, where TargetCollection ist instantiated when its constructor is called. At some point however, I will need to be able to load different configurations of the edited objects from disk and I can't see ATM how this will be done using the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, we assign view models to the view's `DataContext` property.

You can do this from code as long as you have a reference to the view. Here is the code:

#### C Sharp

```
Window view = new Window();

// add a view model
view.DataContext = new ViewModel() { Title = "View Model 1" };
view.Show();

// add another view model to demonstrate the binding
view.DataContext = new ViewModel() { Title = "View Model 2" };
```

#### XAML

The XAML for window might look something like this.

```
<Window Title={Binding Title}>
</Window>
```

Notice how the `Source` or `ElementName` properties remains unspecified in the binding declaration? This instructs the Binding to use the current `DataContext` as the source.

Comment: Where is your C Sharp code placed? Because it looks like its placed on the ViewModel and I think that this is MVVM breaking.

Comment: In this instance I'd probably put it in `App.xaml.cs`. You may also do it in a parent view model. But you don't have a reference to the view at that point. Drive it all with data binding! Gluing component parts together at the start of an application is known as _bootstrapping_. In larger systems there is often a framework that provides a navigation system provided to help achieve the same for while the application is running..

Comment: @Gusdor Thanks for the answer! I think it is spot on to my question and I will try it and accept ASAP. What you describe seems trivial. I guess its all a bit too many concepts at once and confusing to me. Regarding your comment about the framework: Would this be something like MVVM Light, Prism and the like?! If so when do these frameworks make sense (e.g. application size, etc.) and if doing things as you wrote in your answer, could I later "retrofit" my application using a framework?

Comment: Mvvm is odd at first but keep at it and will click eventually! I use Prism 6 exclusively for all new production level WPF projects. For toys, samples and console utilities I often don't bother. This doesn't mean Prism is the best, but I like it. I recommend using a framework from the start.

Comment: @Gusdor Hi again. So I am now trying out your suggestion, but I am still doing something wrong. Perhaps you can take a look at it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @packoman the code you have inserted is not in a method and won't compile :-)

Comment: @Gusdor Ok. That was a little dumb of me. So I added a constructor to App.xaml.cs (see above), but something is still not correct, because it is still not working. :(

Comment: @Gusdor Ok. Sorry. Forgot to add `View.Show();`. Now it works. Had to remove `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` so that the window is not opend twice... Thank you very much!

Comment: App.xaml defines the StartupUri as MainWindow. Remove that.

Comment: @Gusdor Yeah. I just figured that out and update the previous comment. Thanks again so much!

Comment: Any time sir. Godspeed and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

**Model** = business.
**View** = what the user see, and really ain't about logic (this is a lie ofcourse, but this is what you strive for).
**ViewModel** = what glues them together. It's your adapter that gives the *View* the info it needs from the *Model* you have.

I suggest having a look at an MVVM platform (like MVVM Light), which gives you lot of the stuff you need to do "for free" when you begin.

As a guide, here are 3 options for doing your binding:

1. 1.1 On the XAML, set `DataContext = "{Binding relativeSource={RelativeSource self}}`
   1.2 have a property on the code behind (your xaml.cs)
   1.3 Initialize the property BEFORE the `InitializeComponent()` in the constructor.
2. 2.1 Igonre `DataContext` on the XAML 
   2.2 In the code behind, start with `InitializeComponent();` 
   2.3 have a line like `DataContext = this;` in the constructor 
   2.4 Initialize your properties
3. 3.1 Give the window or UserControl a name: `Name = "MyWindow"` (in the xaml) 
   3.2 Bind to an element: `ItemSource={Binding ElementName = MyWindow, path =... }"`
   3.3 Initialize the property BEFORE the `InitializeComponent()` in the constructor.

And last but not least, have a look at my article ["The Big MVVM Template"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/768427/The-big-MVVM-Template), which you can follow and will give you a good handle of the basic, plus you'll have a running fully documented example on top :) .

Comment: Thank you for options. I will definitely look into your tutorial. It looks great. In the end (and for the moment) I went with and accepted Gusdor's answer, since it helped get it running. But thanks so much anyway for your answer.

Comment: @packoman no worries. have fun reading and leave a comment there if you found it useful  :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more about design then coding. I think if you have existing instances of viewmodels already and you just want to reuse/reassign them in new views. then probably you need to have a look at IOC Containers( as actually you want some sort of dependency injection here)

To be very simple use an IOC container to maintain the lifetime of your viewModel.
Configure the container to give you the required ViewModel according to your need i.e a new object or an existing view model object.

[Unity Container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx)

In unity Container you can just register your objects and resolve them at future as you need them. using below syntax simplay:

Register:

```
 1.MyUnityConatiner.RegisterInstance<IMyService>(myDataService);
or
 2.MyContainer.RegisterInstance<IMyService>("Email", myEmailService);
```

Resolve :

```
  1.MyUnityConatiner.Resolve<IMyService>();
or
  2.MyConatiner.Resolve<IMyService>("Email");
```

I know this will seem to you a little deviated solution but if you learn to use this you will have a different perspective on your problem and how to reuse the objects(model/viewmodel).